# azure function not logging exceptions to application insight

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights

I have azure function that has service bus topic trigger. I am noting that when function executes without any exceptions then all tracewriter.loginformation message appear properly in application insights. but if any exception occurs then nighther log.information is shown nor log.error is shown in appinsights

My function running under consumption plan. I noted that i have 2 catch blocks.

```
catch(validation ex) 
{
    log.error;
} 
catch(exception ex) 
{ 
   log.error; 
   throw;
}
```

all errors in first catch block getting logged but all errors in second catch block not getting logged. i commented out throw and it started logging to appinsights.. but i need throw for deadlettering. please advise.

```
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net462</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.6.15</Version>
    <DependsOnNETStandard>netstandard1.5</DependsOnNETStandard>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    <WarningsAsErrors />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http" Version="1.0.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus" Version="2.1.0-beta1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.0-alpha6" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IO" Version="4.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="TemplateResource.Designer.cs">
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DependentUpon>TemplateResource.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Update="TemplateResource.resx">
      <Generator>ResXFileCodeGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>TemplateResource.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: is the log error part in the second catch block exactly the same?  or is there something else in there that is throwing another exception or something that causes that to not be logged.  that looks like it should work, presuming that log part of your code is *exactly* the same in both branches.

Comment: We tried to repro and it works as expected. Krishna, can you please provide these details: essential code snippet, version of .NET, Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions and Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus packages

Comment: @ZakiMa i updated with project settings details.   i noted that messages get logged in application insights when am debugging from local..  but when deployed in consumption plan it was not working untile i remove the "throw"

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem in that `log.Error`("my error message") was always resulting in a Trace in Application Insights instead of an Exception (which is what I wanted). After inspecting the source code of the Application Insights SDK it became apparent that to get an Exception in Application Insights you must pass an exception object into the **LogError** call.

**Example:**

```
log.Error(ex, "my error message") - will result in Application Insight Exception

log.Error("my error message") - will result in Application Insight Trace
```

Comment: Good find mate, I was also calling it the wrong way around, it uses a different overloaded method

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when logging a message or excpeption to Application Insights with `null` or `string.Empty` the exception is not saved in Application Insights even though it shows up in the local Application Insights preview window in Visual Studio.

To mitigate that I've checked the message with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and replaced it with e.g. the string `"No message"`.

In your case that would mean something like this:

```
// Preventing an empty message from being logged.
var message = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ex.Message) ? "No message" : ex.Message;
log.error(ex, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to repro it with your versions and it still works for me.

```
try
{
    if (new Random().NextDouble() > 0.5)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("null");
    }

    throw new Exception("some exception");
}
catch (ArgumentNullException)
{
    log.Error("null");
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    log.Error("some exception");
    throw;
}
```

I see both: 'null' and 'some exception' in Application Insights.

[image]

BTW, there is already stable Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.14, it should include many fixes since 1.0.0-alpha6.

Comment: ok thanks i will monitor it again..  1.0.14 of sdk has hard dependency on newtonsoft 9.0.1 and it was breaking our functions for file not found errors..